# How much to charge for projects transferred to you?

Tags: website-design, print-design, freelance

I've been doing freelance design for a while, and some marketing agency is interested in my work. They want to transfer projects to me, most likely when they have a big workload.

They offered me 50% of the project price. They will be dealing with clients and I'll do the design work.

**Is this a fair deal?**

Do you, experienced designers, encourage me to accept their offer?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean they split the project price 50/50 with you, or that they offered you 50% of the price you quoted?

Comment: Also I think 'transfer projects' is probably the wrong way to describe what's happening. It's more likely that they are hiring you, sub contracting or acting as an agent for you. Either way I don't think anyone will be able to tell you if it is a good deal or not without knowing the specifics.

Comment: @CaiMorris if they ,for example, would do branding for a client for 1000$; I will do the design and take 500$ and they will take 500$

Comment: Ok. I still don't think anyone will be able to answer your question though, if they do it will be an uninformed guess. Specifics on any contract etc will need to be taken in to account. Also things like, what your costs and overheads are, how it compares to your usual rates etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a fair deal?

Depends on what it's 50% of.

50% of $100 is a lot different than 50% of $10,000

As long as the fee covers your standard rate, then sure, it's 'fair' in the context of any other work you do.

UPDATE: Based on your comment...

> I will do the design and take 500$ and they will take 500$

That may *not* be fair in the context of *who's doing the work*. Sounds like this is more of a sales commission type model. The big red flag I see here is it sounds like they're the ones 'selling' the project at a particular price point, but you're the one that actually has to do the work and, as such, you're really the only one that can estimate the true cost of the project.

As such, this could clearly be a risk, or a huge benefit. If this firm is capable of selling projects way over the estimated cost, you might come out ahead. On the other hand, if they sell every project at a low cost, you may end up losing money on each project once you take into account your expenses and time.